# Draw circle on ImageView at touched point

Tags: java, android, view, imageview

I am trying to draw circle on `ImageView` at touched point but it draws at left top corner.

My code is

```
ImageView imageView;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    Bitmap bmp;
    float touchY;
    float touchX;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touchX = event.getX();
                    touchY = event.getY();
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(drawCircle());
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }


                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private Bitmap drawCircle() {
        Bitmap bitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444, true);
        bitmap.setPixel(imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight(), 0);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(touchX, touchY, 100, paint);
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.getimage:
            pickImage();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void pickImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
    }
```

and xml is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am not getting what is wrong. I want to draw circle at touched point. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would create a new bitmap with the size of ImageView this code would work fine.

However the "bmp" bitmap is probably much larger then the ImageView and is scaled. That's why you get distorted result.